# c Creating a program that counts how many words are in a sentence and also capitalizes all the letters in the sentence.

Tags: c

So i have this code but when i run it it always says that the amount of words are 1 no matter how many i put in and hopefully it is in easy fix. I tried changing the scanf to just %s  but that didn't work because it only printed out the first word but it got the number of words right.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
     int words = 0;
     char ch,sen[100]="", i;
     printf("Enter a sentence ended by a '.', a '?', or a '!':");
      scanf("%[^\n]", sen);
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (ch == ' ')
        words++;
    }
    words++;

   for(i=0;sen[i];i++)
 {
         if( (sen[i]>=97) && (sen[i]<=122) )
                    sen[i]-=32;
     }

    printf("Capitalized sentence: %s\n", sen);
    printf("Total number of words:%d\n", words);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a major bug. scanf() won't read/store the newline. Then the newline is read by getchar(). This loop will only execute once.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
if (ch == ' ')
    words++;
}
```

Hence you are getting only 1 word. Why you are using 2 methods to take input.

Either use scan() and manipulate variable "sen" or use getchar() and store character 1 by 1 in sen.

```
// don't use scanf() in this case
i=0;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
if (ch == ' ')
    words++;
sen[i++] = ch;
}
```

Recommended will be to use fgets() to get such inputs. Learn about it.

Comment: What happens if there are two or more `spaces` together?

Comment: My motto was to let the OP understand the problem with his program.. then he can go ahead to handle special cases..!!